# Why does a second call to discover() result in an import error?

Tags: python, import, python-unittest

I want to run both two separate test suites, using the standard library `unittest`.

Specifically, I want to use the `load_tests` approach to test discovery, as described in the documentation for [`unittest.discover()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover).

However, I found that, regardless of the test suite contents, the second test suite would fail to load. I created a MRE like so:

Suppose the test suites are called `x` and `y`, with a directory structure like so:

```
Main.py
test_cases/
    __init__.py
    x/
        __init__.py
        <more individual modules for tests>
    y/
        __init__.py
        <individual modules for tests>
```

where `Main.py` is a driver script containing:

```
import unittest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_test_suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('test_cases/x', pattern='__init__.py')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(x_test_suite)

    y_test_suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('test_cases/y', pattern='__init__.py')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(y_test_suite)

    unittest.main()
```

In each `__init__.py`, I `import unittest` and then define `load_tests` to return a `unittest.TestSuite` instance, like so:

```
import unittest

# In the actual code, I import the other test modules and use
# them to populate the `TestSuite` that is returned, but this
# is not relevant to causing the error.

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    return unittest.TestSuite()
```

The result is that the `x` suite runs (and, for this MRE, all 0 tests are successful), but the `y` suite cannot be loaded and an `ImportError` occurs (paths redacted):

```
$ python Main.py 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 7, in <module>
    y_test_suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('test_cases/y', pattern='__init__.py')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 349, in discover
    tests = list(self._find_tests(start_dir, pattern))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 405, in _find_tests
    tests, should_recurse = self._find_test_path(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 458, in _find_test_path
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: '__init__' module incorrectly imported from '/path/to/test_cases/x'. Expected '/path/to/test_cases/y'. Is this module globally installed?
```

If I try swapping the order in `Main.py` to try loading the `y` suite first, then it runs successfully while `x` fails to import.

I also tried using `pattern='*.py'` for the `.discover` calls and removing the `load_tests` implementations (to let `unittest` do its own discovery), but this also doesn't resolve the problem. Neither does reordering `Main.py` to do both `.discover` calls first and then both `TextTestRunner` calls. In fact, having both `.discover` calls causes the error even without any attempt to run the tests.

Why does the second test discovery fail, and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: What happens if you try doing them in the other order? Is the problem actually with trying to do test discovery twice (like the question title implies), or with the suite itself? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. I know you have written and shown a lot, but this is still the start of research, not the end. A proper question will end up showing much **less**, because you will have put in the time to **determine what is relevant** to the problem.

Comment: Anyway, [please do not use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) to show code or error messages. We [will not transcribe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/) them for you. By policy, when assessing whether a question meets site standards, these screenshots *effectively do not exist* and do not count as providing information. (You have asked almost a hundred questions on Stack Overflow with an account now over 5 years old, so you should fully understand how this works by now.)

Comment: There is nothing in your screen shots that could not be reproduced in plain text.

Comment: (A side note about proper MREs: rather than blanking out parts of file names, start over and create a new project that reflects the problem, using file names that aren't compromising. This is going to be a necessary step **anyway** in pinpointing the problem - i.e., which files need to be in the project to cause the problem? What code needs to be in those files?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the images have been removed and replaced with appropriate text. Also I tried the different order of suites and the same issue popped up. I am confident that it is simply the second call to discover and the other sections I added are to show that I did spend the effort attempting to prove that something else was the case.

Comment: I was able to verify that the error is reproducible even without any test cases (`import`s are removed and an empty `TestSuite` is returned), and that it is indeed the second import that fails regardless.

Comment: I did slightly more investigation, minimized the MRE, edited the question to be considerably shorter, and confirmed my suspicion about what is going on. I will attempt an answer now.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought I knew how to fix it, but I didn't get anywhere with anything I was trying. The issue is that the first discovery call puts a `__init__` entry into `sys.modules`, thus interfering with the second call. However, I never use any of this test discovery machinery myself, so I don't know how to write it correctly. Nothing obvious seemed to work in my own tests. It might be a good idea to add back a minimal example of what `load_tests` is doing (have it import only one module, and show such a module with hello-world test contents).